# C# convert round up textbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, math, rounding

I have a text box where I can enter numeric data which I can have decimals up to two decimal places, example `125.02` or just `125`. However, I want to round all data that is entered with a decimal up, example `125.55` would equal `126`. Below is a snippet of my broken code. Any suggestions would be great!

```
int num6 = (int)Math.Ceiling(textBox5.Text);
```

Comment: Please make sure to always include the exact error you are getting.

Comment: @soner textBox5.Text is a string value, so AFAIK this would throw an exception as Math.Ceiling will not take a string

Comment: @geedubb Yeap. I mentioned in my answer about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to covert the string to a double. Try this:

```
int num6 = (int)Math.Ceiling(double.Parse(textBox5.Text));
```

or safer to use double.TryParse:

```
int num6;
double d;
if(double.TryParse(textBox5.Text, out d)
{
   num6 = (int)Math.Ceiling(d);
} else {
   //Bad input value - perhaps flag this to user
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[`Math.Ceiling`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Math.Ceiling%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method has 2 overloads;

- [`Math.Ceiling Method (Double)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx4t0t48%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [`Math.Ceiling Method (Decimal)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1cz5da1c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

It doesn't have an overload takes `string` as a parameter. You need to parse your `string` like;

```
decimal d;
if(Decimal.TryParse(textBox5.Text, out d))
{
   int num6 = (int)Math.Ceiling(d);
}
```